# unnecessary partition mounted

Tags: linux-mint, boot, partition

Every time I boot up or log in, a partition gets mounted on the Desktop that is not needed. In the boot messages (/var/log/messages) I see a line like this:

```
kernel: [224694.426188] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null).
```

I have confirmed that there is no such thing in the fstab, but I am unable to find out why it is getting mounted.

Of course, it doesn't cause any problem other than putting an icon on the Desktop.

But I am intrigued about why it is getting mounted. I unmount it every time I see it, but it reappears if I just logout and login.

I have two other partitions with GNU/Linux installed, apart from the Mac OSX in one partition. I have used the other Linux OSes too earlier, with the same /home partition, so I was wondering if I had mounted this partition on an occasion when I had booted into one of the other OSes.

Wondered if there is any way I can find out who has mounted this partition.

As suggested by Hauke Laging I am adding this to the question:

I got this from the systemctl status command: proc-fs-nfsd.mount - NFSD configuration filesystem Loaded:
loaded (/lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount; static; vendor preset: enabled) Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2020-06-10 16:51:48 IST; 18h ago Where: /proc/fs/nfsd What: nfsd Process: 257 ExecMount=/bin/mount nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd -t nfsd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915) CGroup: /system.slice/proc-fs-nfsd.mount

### responses to comments and questions

```
$ systemctl status proc-fs-nfsd.mount
proc-fs-nfsd.mount - NFSD configuration filesystem
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount; static; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2020-06-10 16:51:48 IST; 18h ago
    Where: /proc/fs/nfsd
    What: nfsd
    Process: 257 ExecMount=/bin/mount nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd -t nfsd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915) CGroup: /system.slice/proc-fs-nfsd.mount
```

Comment: What is the partition?

Comment: Which operating system/distribution do you have? It might be systemd automount. Does the id for /dev/sda4 (listed in `sudo blkid`) match a line in /etc/fstab?

Comment: See https://systemd.io/DISCOVERABLE_PARTITIONS/

Comment: I am using Linux Mint Debian Edition Cindy right now, but have Debian Buster and Mint on other partitions apart from the original Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not know anyway:

```
awk '$1=="/dev/sda4" { print $2; exit; }' /proc/mounts
```

gives you the mount point. There is a respective entry in the output of

```
systemctl --type mount
```

Running

```
systemctl status xyz.mount
```

shows you why the volume has been mounted, e.g.

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
```

Comment: Thank you. I got this from the systemctl status command:
proc-fs-nfsd.mount - NFSD configuration filesystem
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2020-06-10 16:51:48 IST; 18h ago
    Where: /proc/fs/nfsd
     What: nfsd
  Process: 257 ExecMount=/bin/mount nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd -t nfsd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/proc-fs-nfsd.mount

Comment: So much text is hard to read and thus should be added to the question instead.

Comment: @Sasi `sda4` cannot be mounted at `/proc/fs/nfsd`.